# creating an object out of array php codeigniter for login system

Tags: php, codeigniter, getter-setter, magic-methods

i have a simple question, i'm creating a simple login system, and i want to assign user info into model class after success login,

example model

```
class user extends CI_Model {
    public $id=FALSE,$name,$role;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

    //load user information
        if($this->session->userdata('user')){
            $u=$this->session->userdata('user');
            $this->id=$u->id;
            $this->role=$u->role;
            $this->name=$u->name;
        }

    }
    function login(){......}
```

but this just dont look right to me !! its ugly and not dry..

so should i use magic _*set,*_get ? or can i do something like `$this=$this->session->userdata('user');`

objective for me is since this model is on my Autoload, i want to be able to get user info from any other model/controller using simple `$id=$user->id` Or 
`if($user->id)echo"hello".$user->name;`

now if i do.

```
    private $data;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data = (object) $this->session->userdata('user');
    }
    public function __get($name) {
    if(isset($this->data->$name)){
        return $this->data->$name;
        }
    }
```

this will create an error "Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object"

i thinks thats because __get capture the $this->session ! so how can i fix this ?!

Comment: foreach ( $u as $k => $v ) $this->$k = $v; something like this might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply...

```
if($this->session->userdata('user')){
    $this->data = $this->session->userdata('user');
}
```

... and then later on you can access `$user->data->id`. Also this approach will be more flexible in the future if you add more attributes to your user data.

Comment: my boss doesnt like it :(.. he want $user->id ! i guess i can use as u recommend and write a __get to get it from data :D !